# Nautilus-Actions Configuration Tool -- Archive Manager -- Show a specific option in selected cases

Tags: 14.04, nautilus, nautilus-actions

I have managed to make a new entry to Nautilus right click menu in order to extract a compressed file to a specified folder. My problem is now that when I right click at any file either it is a compressed or a simple file/folder it shows that custom option.Is there a way to make this custom option to show up on the right click menu of nautilus only when I click on one or more compressed files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Mimetypes settings for that action. You'll need to add all the archive types you wish to see the action  on individually. (adding in this case is easier than excluding.

Screen shows adding for .zip, .tar.xz, .tar.gz & .tar.bz2

[image]

Comment: Thank you! In case someone is wondering where to find the Mimetypes;they are located to /usr/share/applications/file-roller.desktop